# Help with Proof for intermediate analysis course

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I am a little stuck on how to prove this statement and would appreciate some help.

Prove that $\sqrt{1+y}< \frac{1+y}{2}$ for all $y>0$.

Thanks!!

Comment: I believe you meant $\sqrt{1+x}<1+(x/2)$.

Comment: We'd be happy to *help* you with your proof, provided you participate in the process.  How about you start first, by providing your attempts, as @user1337 suggests, even if you get stuck, and then explain specifically what you don't understand.  Else when you request help you are basically telling us to do all the work for you.  Things don't work like that on this site: *asking for help $\neq$ *telling us to prove your problem statement for you.*

Comment: That this inequality can't be true can easily be seen with $y = 1$, which would yield $1.41 \ldots = \sqrt{2} < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $4+4y<y^2+4y+4$ holds for all $y>0$.